# How to combine three tables for a queue in each Store in each town?

Tags: mysql, join, table

Sorry if my question is no appropriate for DA.

I have a `State-city` table with unique id for every town/city name. (id: town --> city --> State)

I also have a list of Store names associated to each town. (less than 20 Stores for each town). Call this table `Stores`

In my app, I want users to register. I will store them in another table call `Users`.

In my app I have a button allow users to take queue number for their selected town.

Now I don't know how to put these tables together for queue such that:

- One can save (for 1 month) each day's queue table of each towns with all details.
- One can add or remove a customer to each queue when Store is online,
- The size of the database is important for me.

Do you recommend to take town of users when they register? I have no idea whether this is a useful information or not.

My idea is that for each day and each town I should create a table (probably using `join` but how to save this table?) with unique name e.g. `id-of-town + date` (so how can one add date to table name?) then add customers id, town id and store id to this table. What is your solution?

**Edit:** I expect the final database size to be less or around 1 GB. Also, my estimate of the number of stores is 1000 (within 1 year from launch) and ideally it would be up to 1.5 million stores. (after years). From the comments it looks like I need to create a table for each store.

Comment: @ITThugNinja: Done! my answer sets table name as `2022-12-18` . Is that Ok?

Comment: What controls "when Store is online"?

Comment: "size of the database" -- Are you expecting _billions_ of stores or users or queue entries?  A million of anything is "small" in database usage.

Comment: "each day and each town I should create a table" -- NO!  Have a single table with columns for day and town.

Comment: @RickJames: I mean size less than or around 1GB if that is possible. :)

Comment: A 1GB table holds perhaps 10M rows.  Still not big enough to warrant separate tables per day.  Note also that each table takes at least one OS file in a directory.  With 365 files per year in a single directory, the OS starts to groan.

Comment: Please add to your Question an estimate of how many tables will be needed after a year and a rough estimate of the total size.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial Answer:** I find a query for creating a table with date as its name:

```
set @dynamicQuery = CONCAT('create table `', curdate(), '` as select ColName from TableName');
prepare st from @dynamicQuery;
execute st;
```

Comment: Please do not encourage a new table each day.  It is really bad practice.  (This is a common question; the answer is always "NO".)